# Defaulting to a InfoPath View when editing an item

Tags: list, infopath, sharepoint-views

I've created two views in InfoPath and I'm using a Workflow to send out URLS to two views

http://myspsite.com/sites/it/Tools/Lists/Infrastructure%20Specification%20v2/DispForm.aspx?ID=7&InfrastructureSoftwareSpecREADONLY

http://myspsite.com/sites/it/Tools/Lists/Infrastructure%20Specification%20v2/DispForm.aspx?ID=7&NetworkConfigurationREADONLY

The end objective is that different views/sections can be sent out to the user once a previous one has been approved.

If I click on the NetworkConfigurationREADONLY view and click Edit item I get the option to change the Current View. It shows the Default View, which in this case is Hardware Specs.

If I change the view to NetworkConfigurationREADONLY it gives me the same URL. In fact I get the same URL for all the views. How can I get a unique URL for a user to add to that particular view?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint and InfoPath does not work that way. There is no form view that relates to a SharePoint list view. There is only a Display form that is opened when the link is clicked.

But .... inside of InfoPath you can use rules in the Form Load to check the value of a field, like a status field, and then, depending on the value of that status field, switch to a different InfoPath page to be displayed.

What determines which list items show in the two views you built? Are you filtering on a particular column with a particular value? That is your hook. Use the same field in the logic of the Form Load rule to switch to a particular view/page of the IP form.

Comment: That makes sense. So the Display form isn't a webpage, it's basically just a display version.

I haven't got any rules/ logic on the views as of yet. It's actually 4 views/stages. There can be a two to three day time lapse between the different stages being authorised and I wanted the authoriser to be able to send out the next stage when one has been completed. Does that make sense?

Comment: The display form is the DEFAULT display form when the item is opened to view. You can switch to a different InfoPath view by creating Form Load rules, as I have explained above. The same applies to Edit form, of course. You only need one link to the Edit form and then let the Form Load rules determine which IP view to switch to, so the user only sees the fields you want them to see/edit at this stage in the business logic.

Comment: Brilliant, yes I can see how that would work. Thanks

Comment: Just one more question. What would be the best condition to add? I've set the rule to run when myFields is not blank but what happens is that it switches views when I preview and what I want it to do is to switch views after the fields on the view have been filled in and submitted.

Comment: Well, then check the fields that have been filled in/or not filled in and switch views depending on whether or not a specific field is blank. A mandatory field would be easiest. If none of the fields are mandatory, you may need to check several fields to determine if the view needs to be switched. I think that answers your question as stated. Any follow ups should go into a new question after you close this one by accepting an answer.